# Random text in linux terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, debian

Sup guys. How I can make terminal to show the text that I want ? And how to edit the text that is already displayed
For example terminal is showing now:

```
user@host: sudo writetext 
bash: writetext: command not found
```

How to edit this text to be displayed like this

```
user@host: sudo writetext  5
 writelext line 1 executed
 writelext line 2 executed
 writelext line 3 executed
 writelext line 4 executed
 writelext line 5 executed
```

I don't need the program to work, i just need to know how to display random text in terminal

Comment: what you mean by random text? When should it be displayed?

Comment: i just need to make terminal to display text that i will type. To do a screenshot.

Comment: Can you provide some more example?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to print text to stdout, you should read some man pages:

```
man echo
man print
man printf
```

more powerful tools:

```
sed, awk ...
```

Examples:

#### seq

```
kent$  seq -f "whatever %g" 5
whatever 1
whatever 2
whatever 3
whatever 4
whatever 5
```

#### awk

```
kent$  awk -v v=5 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=v;i++)print "whatever "i}' 
whatever 1
whatever 2
whatever 3
whatever 4
whatever 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an alias to the bashrc

1. vim ~/.bashrc
2. Go to the end of the file
3. add line: alias writeText='echo "write text executed"'
4. Then reload the bashrc with: source ~/.bashrc

After this you should be able to call the alias by typing in **writeText**

Here you can also add a more advanced echo function.

If you want to pass parameters you have to write a separate function as described here:
[Passing argument to alias in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060880/passing-argument-to-alias-in-bash)

Answer (score 1):

Write a shell script and add echo commands inside to display whatever u want to display

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying "make the terminal display text that I will type."

You could try `read`, assign a variable to the read and then echo it

```
read text
echo "${text}"
```